# PHP PDO class use in different class (doesn't work)

Tags: php, class, pdo, extends

I wanna get data on table and write a class. But this class doesn't work because pdo doesn't access. How can I get table data with this class?

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx;charset=utf8", "xxx", "xxx");


class uye extends PDO{
    var $id;
    var $kadi;

    function cek($id){
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM btc WHERE id='{$id}'", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ( $query->rowCount() ) { 
          foreach( $query as $row ){
              $this->id=$row["id"];
              $this->kadi=$row["kadi"];
          }
        }
    }
}


$bilgiler=new uye;
$bilgiler->cek(1);

echo $bilgiler->kadi;
```

Comment: Can you post the other file that you're calling this class from

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL injections here too within your statement

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Your class extends PDO yet tries to use another PDO instance. What do you want to accomplish doing that?

Comment: I want declare a class and I send parameter this class. Then this request return table datas to me

Comment: @Yunus, I've given you a low down on this.. but I haven't fetched by the ID as the ID is generally AI therefore it'd only return 1 piece of data and not a bunch of data like you're after.. You also didnt give us what makes `$id`.

Comment: Then get rid of `extends PDO` and add `$db` to `$id` among method parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm running this off of fetching all data as I dont know where you're getting `$id` from.

I generally break my code up into files and folders as I found this easier to work with and others to work on.

```
// database connection file (dbc.php)



class Database
{
    private $host = "127.0.0.1";
    private $db = "";
    private $user = "";
    private $password = "";
    public $conn;



    public function dbConnect()
    {
        $this->conn = null;
        try
        {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db, $this->user, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch (PDOException $exception)
        {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;

    }
}
```

I then make a common file, this is where you can store all of your frequently used functions or your static functions

```
// Common file (common.php)


require_once('dbc.php');

class DBCommon
{
    private $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnect();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function run($sql)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt;
    }


}
```

So to explain this a little more, you will see a function of `run()` this is just to save the tedious `$this->conn->prepare` on every query.. Now you can run `$this->run()`

The next would be your class file.. this is where your logic goes:

```
// your class file... (class.btc.php)


require_once "common.php";


class BTC extends DBCommon

{
    public function getQuery()
    {
        $stmt = $this->run("SELECT * FROM `btc`");
        $stmt->execute();

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
        {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }

        return $rows;

    }

}
```

Self explanatory..

And then your calling method.. Lets say `index.php`

```
// File you're calling your class from (index.php)


    require_once "class.btc.php";

    $fetch = new BTC();

    $returnData = $fetch->getQuery();


    foreach ($returnData as $data)
    {
        echo
        "<p>$data->something</p>
        <p>$data->somethingElse</p>";
    }
```

It seems a little long winded I know, but the time you'll save overall will help!

Comment: thanks for helps. but this method very long. Do you know shortest method?

Comment: Related: [Reporting PDO errors](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#reporting_errors) and [Catching PDO exceptions](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#catch)

Comment: @Yunus, It's a long process at the beginning yes however, one the initial files are setup, it's a lot faster.

Comment: @Option Thanks. I did it but now there is different problem. Can you look this question? -> [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44565237/php-pdo-query-in-class-doesnt-show-first-row)